# Typerror when calling a flask function from template

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

So very simple... I'm calling this sort_by function in my template like this:

```
{{ sort_by('a') }}
```

It only takes one argument, but for some reason I get the following error:

```
TypeError: sort_by() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

@app.context_processor
def sort_by(aa):
    print("sort byyyyyyyyyy")
    print(aa)
```

Any idea why? Also `@app.context_processor` is needed whenever I want to call a function that doesn't have a route from a template?

Comment: I think you have a typo in `{{ sortt_by('a') }}`, hence the `sortt` instead of `sort`. Try this instead: `{{ sort_by('a') }}`

Comment: My bad, the typo isn't there, I tried sortt because I thought sort_by could be reserved... So that's not the issue here. Also if I remove @app.context.processor I get undefined function. If I leave it and remove all parameters then I can call the function... But not with parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think that a context processor should'nt be defined like this when it has parameters, look there: [Flask context processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#context-processors)

Comment: Is it normal that I need it? From what I'm reading I don't really need what a conext processor can do, I just want to call a function that has no route from a template